# Which In App Purchase should use in following case?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

Application is about selling Audio books.

**Option 1** : Consumable In App Purchase

It Will have different product ids with common price.

**e.g.** **Audio A** and **Audio B** both have **price $2** then both Audio A and Audio B will share common product id.
All user purchase will be managed from server

**Option 2** : Non Consumable In App Purchase

Will have different product ids for each audio.

I am confuse because there could be 10k + Audios. Can we create dynamic Non Consumable item ?

Any ideas how to make this scalable?

Comment: You will need to use consumable in-app purchase for a "virtual currency" and then allow your users to redeem this currency for the audio books

Answer (score 0):

For that amount of dynamic content you will probably have to implement some kind of custom "currency" which would be a consumable item.
You can either make it completely arbitrary in amount, or you could try to make a few different IAP products to correspond with audio books in different price ranges. So something like *$0.99$ book purchase*, *$1.99 book purchase*, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Apple allows up to 1000 in app purchase products to be created. So you cannot create 10k+ products. Also finding the product amongst this will be a very complex task for the user. See if you can bundle books of same price into a single bundle and price them economically so that users tend to purchase. 10 books for 10$ is better than 20$.

You should definitely go with non-consumable option since audio books do not deplete in time.

You have to maintain your own server in between the app and the Apple in app purchase and you need to have a user account management to track what books the user has purchased. You can create a different SKU For each price and and associate the product id with the book on your server and track the purchases done by the user on your own. Since multiple books could map to the same in-app product id, your app should handle the restoring purchases explicitly and based on your app user login enable the audio books on different devices.

Basically the in app flow would be used just for payment purposes. Enabling and downloading of the audio books will have to be controlled between your app and the server.

Answer (score -1):

I would use something like a 2-Dimensional int array. [x][y] whereas *x* is your **individual product ID**, and *y* is the count on how many items are sold. You can then always link your x to a certain price. This way you can easily keep track on how many audio files '*y*' with product ID '*x*' got bought.
Never give two different audio files with maybe equivalent price the same ID. An ID should always be unique since there are a lot of problems that might occur later:

- Implementing the audio files in a seperate database
- Audio file becomes cheaper/more expensive, then you´d have to use another ID anyway